# Web apps using fullstack javascript + mobile

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I Have a question for my course i have to make a web app using "node.js". So i decided to make a little app where i have a list of items in mongodb and search for a specific item in the list. if i search on a part of the word it will give me only that item

but what should i use for making this app? my teacher tells me things like restfull/ angular/ reactjs / ionic. With all these tools I get a bit lost.

What i want to use is the tool that will be used and that I can grow with it. What are your advices for a beginner? thank you in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a framework that is backed by a strong community. React is backed by Facebook while Angular is backed by Google.